# BigQuery- Grant view permission for many users of other projects?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have Big-Query on project PRJ-A with 30 datasets

**Question:**

1/ If we have another project (ex: PRJ-B). How can we  grant view permission on PRJ-A for all users on PRJ-B ? (it means: user_01 on PRJ-B can select "dataset" of PRJ-A)

2/ If we have a group user (ten users) and they have not VISA and we do not want to add them to our PRJ-A (because they can view our information about instance,app,configurations ... )
How can we grant view permission for them ? (may be we can use a global user for ten users)

Until now, we intend to use "bq command" to solve : install gcloud sdk tool on server A, after that, grant privileges to ten users can use bq command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1, there is no way to reference all users of Project A in ACL for project B. So, your best options I see : domain or userByEmail or groupByEmail depends on your specifics
If you would need to reference Users of the same project - specialGroup would be your choice

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets#resource

For #2
I think, groupByEmail (An email address of a Google Group to grant access to.) is your option

[image]

Comment: thanks - we will try. And thanks for "BigQuery Mate"

Comment: @ Mikhail Berlyant : sorry about that. I did not remember check it.